# N-digit geometric numbers which relate to arithmetic progression

Tags: arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

Call a $3$-digit number geometric if it has $3$ distinct digits which, when read from left to right, form a geometric sequence. So, consider the number $931$. Let us note $931-792=139$ which means reverse order of $931$.
In over words $9·100+10·3+1-792=100·1+10·3+9$.

In addition to that note that $(9-4)·100+3·10+1=531$, the numbers $1$, $3$, $5$ form arithmetic progression.

The standard way to find the $3$-digit number is to solve the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases} 
b^2 &= ac &\,\,\,(a)\\
2b &= a-4 &\,\,\,(b)\\
100a+10b+c-792 &= 100c+10b+a &\,\,\,(c) \\
\end{cases}$$, here a,b,c - the members of the geometric progression

I wonder if the numbers with similar properties exist amongst $n$-digit number and how to find the numbers avoiding brute force?
I think more clarification about $n$-digit geometric numbers is required and how they are organized. For eg.
the $4$-digit number is $8421$, the $5$-digit number are $10010$, $11111$, $16421$,$81931$.
So, for $4$-digit numbers:
system of equations:
$$\begin{cases} 
b^2 &= ac &\,\,\,(a)\\
c^2 &= bd &\,\,\,(b)\\
2b &= a-4+c &\,\,\,(c)\\
2c &= b+d &\,\,\,(e)\\
1000a+100b+10c+d-792 &= 1000d+100c+10b+a &\,\,\,(f) \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: It's not clear (to me, at least, what pattern you hope to generalize.  And what would a geometric $5$ digit number be?  unless you consider $1111$ to be geometric, but that doesn't seem very interesting.  I suppose $1248$ is a geometric $4$ digit number...does it have the property you like?

Comment: What is the specialty of 792?

Comment: I've tried to clarify via system of equations. $792$ is just make sure the initial $931$ will be in reverse order.

Comment: @lulu $1248$ does not have the property, pls see eq (c) for $4$-digits